# Cisco ASA5505 VPN remote-access user cannot connect to other site-to-site subnet

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-vpn

I am connecting to a ASA5505 at from home to the head-office using L2TP VPN.

Head-office then connects to a other-office via a site-to-site IPSEC tunnel.

When in the head-office (192.168.100.0/24) I can ping/access remote-office (192.168.200.0/24) OK.

When connected remotely to head-office, I can ping/access head-office OK from the road-warrior laptop.

My problem is that when connected remotely from home to the head-office I cannot ping/access the other-office subnet

On the home laptop the L2TP VPN connection is set to route all traffic to the VPN connection using the HQ as the internet gateway I can confirm this works.

I cant do traceroute (I get timeouts) as my policy doesnt allow and not sure how to enable this properly on the ASA.

Any ideas what is wrong, config is below:

```
names
name 192.168.200.0 othersite
!
interface Vlan1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.100.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan2
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 34.35.36.3 255.255.255.252
!
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 othersite 255.255.255.0
access-list inside_nat0_outbound extended permit ip any 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
access-list outside_1_cryptomap extended permit ip 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0 othersite 255.255.255.0
access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl_1 standard permit 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
access-list outside_in_acl extended permit icmp any any echo-reply
access-list outside_in_acl extended permit tcp any interface outside eq smtp
ip local pool VPNLAN 192.168.100.210-192.168.100.240 mask 255.255.255.0
global (outside) 1 interface
nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_nat0_outbound
nat (inside) 1 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
nat (outside) 1 192.168.100.0 255.255.255.0
static (inside,outside) tcp interface smtp 192.168.100.3 smtp netmask 255.255.255.255
access-group outside_in_acl in interface outside
group-policy DefaultRAGroup internal
group-policy DefaultRAGroup attributes
 dns-server value 192.168.100.3
 vpn-tunnel-protocol l2tp-ipsec
 split-tunnel-policy tunnelspecified
 split-tunnel-network-list value DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl_1
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup general-attributes
 address-pool VPNLAN
 default-group-policy DefaultRAGroup
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *****
tunnel-group DefaultRAGroup ppp-attributes
 no authentication chap
 authentication ms-chap-v2
tunnel-group 40.35.36.122 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 40.35.36.122 ipsec-attributes
 pre-shared-key *****
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your split tunnel ACL should encompass the other site's IP addresses, since that traffic should be sent through the VPN by the client.

```
access-list DefaultRAGroup_splitTunnelAcl_1 standard permit 192.168.200.0 255.255.255.0
```

The config looks good, otherwise.  If this doesn't help, then turn up logging on the ASA and see what comes up when you try to send the traffic through.